# C++ pointer of pointers to arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, g++, coredump

I have a bit of a problem with creating an array of arrays, or an array of pointers to arrays to be more precise, I seem to have eliminated all errors because the program compiles just fine (I'm using g++) however when I try to run it it gives a "core dumped" message.

This is my code?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<ctime>
#include<cstdlib>

using namespace std;

void create_array(int **pp)
    {
        pp = new int*[4];
        for (int i = 0; i<4; i++)
        {
            pp[i] = new int[4];
        }
    }

int main()
    {
        srand(time(NULL));
        int **pp;
        create_array(pp);

        for (int x = 0; x<4; x++)
        {
            for(int y = 0; y<4; y++)
            {
                pp[x][y] = rand()%9;
            }
        }
        cout << pp[3][2] << endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: **Compile with all warnings and debugging info `g++ -Wall -g`, learn to use the `gdb` debugger**, and consider using C++ containers (like `std::vector`); your `pp` is an *unitialized* pointer (and the memory zone created by `create_array` is currently unreachable from `main`; consider returning a pointer from `create_array`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 void create_array(int **pp)
{
    pp = new int*[4];
    for (int i = 0; i<4; i++)
    {
        pp[i] = new int[4];
    }
}
```

`pp` is an array of pointers to `int`, however, it is passed by value. so the original caller `pp` in `main` is not affected. `pp` inside `main` remain `uninitialized` after you call the `create_array` function. When you try to assign value to it. it will result in core dump.

try to use `vector <vector<int>>` instead in C++.

Or try:

```
void create_array(int **&pp)
{                     //^^
    pp = new int*[4];
    for (int i = 0; i<4; i++)
    {
        pp[i] = new int[4];
    }
}
```

with the above change, it outputs the following if you try to print the whole matrix on my machine:

```
 8 7 6 3
 3 5 6 4
 3 8 7 6
 0 0 5 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Of you don't want to initialize pointers, do a reference.